# Contents of machine-options.xml for ebuild?

Tags: ebuild

When running [ebuild](http://ebuild-project.org)'s workspace generator (workspace.xml ant task), it finishes with an error saying it could not find machine-options.xml with a series of possible locations.

What should that file contain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file 'machine-options.xml' is a simple way to let ebuild know where to look for Java.

This is the contents of it for me, and I put it in the `~/.ebuild/machine-options.xml` location.

```
<ebuild-machine-options>
  <module org="java" name="jdk.tools">
    <artifact name="java_classes.jar" files="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_45\lib\tools.jar"/>
  </module>
</ebuild-machine-options>
```